# Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat) .Installing cx_oracle module

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I successfully installed Python 3.4.3 and Oracle 11g in my windows7 OS computer. I am trying to connect oracle db by Python. So that i'm trying to install cx_oracle 5.2 module,but while installing, I am getting  below Error.

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

Please anyone help me on this to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I uninstalled 3.4 version and installed python 2.7.10 version.Also installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7.
But i'm getting below error:



build\lib.win-amd64-2.7-11g\cx_Oracle.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 84 unresolved
xternals
error: command 'C:\\Users\\JV\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Vis
al C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Answer (score 0):

You can download binaries from PyPI

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/